# How to develop a windows way toggle button in android?

Tags: android, togglebutton

I need to design a windows kinda toggle button for my android application. I dont know which one to use. I tried using SeekBar & ToggleButton. I am not able to simulate the same way.

[image]

When you click it, it will slide to the other end. Not the exact way of slider.
When you click it during if it is off. It will slide to the other end and make it enabled.

Is there a way in SeekBar that i can achieve. 
For the interface i am gonna use the below icon

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Switch would suit you http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Switch.html ?

Comment: switch is not supported in API Level 8. I need it for android 2.2